# jQuery code that changed the windows.location.href directory if the word 'Cheese' found in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

How to search an h1 element inside a div that has a class .title-bar that contains a word "Cheese"?
If Cheese was found then add a click event to redirect to abcx.com/cheese.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    jQuery("span.xoo-cp-close.xoo-cp-icon-cross")
        .contains('.title-bar h1' "Cheese")
        .attr( "onClick", "window.location.href('abcx.com/cheese')" );
});
```

Thanks for the help, cheers

Comment: is "Cheese" a text in the h1 ? also pls add a minimal html markup to better understand what's your problem.

Comment: Hi JF-Mechs, yes the Cheese is a text in h1 <div class='title-bar'> <h1> Cheese </h1> </div>

Comment: I've posted an answer. Pls check if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your html markup looks like this..

```
<span class="xoo-cp-close xoo-cp-icon-cross">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <h1>Cheese</h1>
  </div>
</span>
```

You can just simply iterate all h1 on document ready like this ..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".title-bar h1", "span.xoo-cp-close.xoo-cp-icon-cross").each(function() {
    var $h1 = jQuery(this),
      h1Text = $h1.text().trim().toLowerCase();

    if (h1Text.indexOf("cheese") > -1) {
      $h1.attr("onClick", "window.location.href('abcx.com/cheese')");
    }
  });
});
```

The code above iterates all `h1` inside an element with a class `.title-bar` that is a descendant of a span element that contains both class `xoo-cp-close` and `xoo-cp-icon-cross`